# Rule of thumb for number of iterations Metropolis Hastings

Tags: metropolis-hastings

Is there a rule of thumb for the number of iterations needed for the Metropolis Hastings algorithm? I would appreciate good references

Answer (score 3):

The plain answer is **no**. Depending on the target complexity and the adequation of the proposal to the target, the number of required simulations varies from one to infinity. Some convergence assessment tools have been devised over the years, primarily in the early days of MCMC, but they are partial and far from fool-proof. We included a chapter on some of these in [our book](http://amzn.to/2kSOnNa).

Comment: I have feared that there is no rule of thumb. But thanks for the answer and the book recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your target distribution and mostly on the dimensionality of your parameter space. Ideally you want to have a lot more samples than your burn-in period (unless you discard it) and you want to have uncorrelated samples. To get uncorrelated samples you would have to look at the autocorrelation plots for the values of your samples and then subsample every n_th value such that your final sample is uncorrelated.